# PSQL: Get every nth value depending on irregular write times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a small PostgreSQL table with two columns:

- time (a Unix timestamp in milliseconds)
- speed (an integer)

**I am inserting values into this table at irregular intervals, sometimes multiple times per minute, and at other times, no writes occur for hours.**

**Currently, I am encountering an issue where I want to retrieve one value for every 5 minutes passed within 24 hours.**

**So in the best possible case, that would be 288 values for 24 hours.**

For instance, between 00:00 and 00:05, there may be 100 entries, and I want to obtain the average of those entries (keeping in mind that I only need one value for every 5th minute). If there are no values between 00:05 and 01:00, no value should be retrieved. Then one value at 01:00 to 01:30, that single value should be the next one I retrieve.

So basically build average if the distance to the next entry is < 5 Minutes. Else take every value.

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't give me the desired result:

```
SELECT
  MIN(time) AS start_time,
  AVG(speed) AS average_data
FROM my_table
WHERE time >= EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours') * 1000
GROUP BY FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM to_timestamp(time / 1000)) / 300)
ORDER BY start_time;
```

Comment: please add a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this just be

```
GROUP BY time / 300000
```

as time is an integer holding the Unix time in milliseconds? We want an integer division (i.e. no fractions in the result) by 300000 (5 minutes in milliseconds), so every five minutes add one to the result. In PostgreSQL it is an integer division by default when you divide one integer by another.

```
SELECT
  MIN(time) AS start_time,
  AVG(speed) AS average_data
FROM my_table
WHERE time >= EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours') * 1000
GROUP BY time / 300000
ORDER BY start_time;
```

Be aware that this looks at fixed defined intervals:

```
>= 00:00:00 and < 00:05:00
>= 00:05:00 and < 00:10:00
>= 00:10:00 and < 00:15:00
etc.
```

So, if there are only two entries

```
00:04:59
00:05:01
```

then both will be shown in the result, although they are only two seconds apart. This does not meet the requirement "So basically build average if the distance to the next entry is < 5 Minutes", but seems to be what you actually want.